# Deleting file by metadata with gridfs in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I am trying to delete files in my mongodb database using gridfs.
I want to delete all the files with the metadata.relation = id.
Here is my method in NodeJS:

```
function deleteFiles(){
    gfs.remove({'metadata.relation': req.body._id }, function(err){
      if (err) return false;
      return true;          
    })
}
```

The error is:

> C:\Users\Gaute\Documents\GitHub\WikiHelpSystem\node_modules\mongoose\node_module
>   s\mongodb\lib\mongodb\gridfs\gridstore.js:1138
>     if(names.constructor == Array) {
>
> ```
>      ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
>       at Function.GridStore.unlink (C:\Users\Gaute\Documents\GitHub\WikiHelpSystem
>   \node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\gridfs\gridstore.js:1138
>   :11)

Comment: you are checking whether `names` is an array or not, but it says it is undefined. What is names? Put some code snippets

Comment: I am not checking this. Its from gridstore.js, a imported file
GridStore.unlink = function(db, names, options, callback) {
  var self = this;
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  callback = args.pop();
  options = args.length ? args.shift() : null;

  if(names.constructor == Array) {

Comment: Can you update the post instead of pasting code in comments?  You need to track names var back through the stack to figure out why it's null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream) module, then when you call `gfs.remove` with an object, it will expect that the object will contain an `_id`.

You need to first get the id, using MongoDb driver.

```
// This should be your files metadata collection, fs.files is the default collection for it. 
var collection = db.collection('fs.files');     
collection.findOne({'metadata.relation': req.body._id }, { _id : 1 }, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) return cb(err); // don't forget to handle error/
    gfs.remove(obj, function(err){
      if (err) return false;
      return true;          
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 gfs.files.remove({_id:_id} , function(err){
                                            if (err){
                                                 console.log("error");
                                            }else{
                                              console.log("old file removed")
                                            }           
                                   });
```